# Python TkInter Buttons Programming

Tags: python, button, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I would like someone to tell me what is wrong with my following code. I want the code to provide a window with 2 buttons one saying 50% and the other 75%.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def _init_(self, master=None):
        super ()._init_(master)
        self.pack()
        self.create_widget1()
        self.create_widget2()

    def create_widget1(self):
        self.test = tk.Button(self)
        self.test["text"] = "50%"
        self.test["command"] = self.choice1
        self.test.pack(side="top")
    def create_widget2(self):
        self.test = tk.Button(self)
        self.test["text"] = "75%"
        self.test["command"] =self.choice2
        self.test.pack(side="bottom")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="black", command=root.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def  choice1(self):
        print ("You have chosen a discount of 50%")
    def choice2(self):
        print ("You have chose a discount of 75%")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Tkinter but you overwrite `self.test` in the call to `create_widget2()`.

Comment: That's ok because it means i am operating within the main function i named test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to use double `_` around `init`. replace

```
def _init_(self, master=None):
        super ()._init_(master)
```

with

```
def __init__(self, master=None):
        super ().__init__(master)
```